# Javacript MediaDevices.getUserMedia() don´t work on Android 11

Tags: javascript, android

I use JavaScript script on my page to decode a QR code. It works on PC, mobiles, but not on phones with Android 11. Does anyone know why? I didn't find any information about that. Tested on several devices.

Here is my code:

```js
btnScanQR.onclick = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({video: {facingMode: "environment"}})
        .then(function (stream) {
            scanning = true;
            btnScanQR.hidden = true;
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            canvasElement.hidden = false;
            video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
            tick();
            scan();
        });
};
```

I tried Remote Debugging. I put this to console:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {facingMode: "environment"}})
```

The console responded:

```
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected" | [[PromiseResult]]: DOMException: Permission denied
```